# setListadapter and getListView() undefine on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I hope you can help me. I am new in android development and I already tried to research about this but I had no luck. I hope you can help me with my simple problem.

How do I use setListAdapter on a fragment? My activity extends fragment and I can't convert it  to listfragment since I am displaying it inside one of my fragment tabs.

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
private LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

private RemindersDbAdapter mDbHelper;

ListView listv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(getActivity());
         mDbHelper.open();
         fillData();

     //registerForContextMenu(getListView());----- Not working too :(

      //intialize variables


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);




            registerForContextMenu(getView());
            listv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remlist);







        return rootView;


         }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fillData();


    }

    private void fillData() {
        Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.reminder_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(reminders);
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.getActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater mi = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu); 
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_insert: 
            createReminder();
            return true; 
        case R.id.menu_settings: 
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskPreferences.class); 
            startActivity(i); 
            return true;
        }

        return super.getActivity().onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater mi = getActivity().getMenuInflater(); 
        mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu_item_longpress, menu); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteReminder(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createReminder() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ReminderEditActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My activity extends fragment and I can't convert it to listfragment since I am displaying it inside one of my fragment tabs.

That doesn't quite make sense to me. Could you perhaps rephrase/elaborate on that?

> How do I use setListAdapter on a fragment

The answer is simple: you don't. It's just one of the convenience methods a `ListFragment` exposes, but you can do exactly the same in a regular `Fragment` by calling the appropriate methods on a `ListView`.

From the looks of it, your layout already has a `ListView`:

```
listv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remlist);
```

Now, just call the relevant methods on the `listv` variable. I.e. the equivalent of `setListAdapter()` is:

```
listv.setAdapter(...);
```

Also, since you already have a handle on the relevant `ListView`, you no longer need to call `getListView()`.

Comment: I tried and it showed this error on                                  logcat     09-01 10:14:12.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-01 10:14:12.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29966):     java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-01 10:14:12.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29966):  at   com.csu.eclassrecord.AccountFragment.fillData(AccountFragment.java:183)
09-01 10:14:12.999: E/AndroidRuntime(29966):  at com.csu.eclassrecord.AccountFragment.onCreateView(AccountFragment.java:57)

Comment: Right, so `listv == null`, which means either your layout does not declare a `ListView`, or it doesn't have `R.id.remlist` as id. Which one it is, is up to you to figure out.

Comment: I finally solved it :) I removed getListView() based on your suggestion. Thanks!